# Web and Database servers on different providers

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn, rackspace

I have currently my setup on Rackspace. Now, I need to double my Db's capacity (memory). The prices are very high compared to AWS. I need to keep my public IP because of access rules by third parties. Therefore, I am thinking of moving only my Db to AWS and keeping my web server in rackspace  (to keep my public IP).

The ping from amazon to rackspace is 0.9-1.2 milliseconds. Do you think this will cause an issue? My web service is an api: there are no web pages involved.

I was thinking of making a vpn between my web server in rackspace and my new aws setup and thus moving my webserver to AWS. That way outgoing connections will still use the same public ip but the lag will be between the incoming/outgoing connections and my webserver in AWS. My humble knowledge in networking tells me that this approach is feasible and better. Is it?

Comment: It's possible, but I'd be careful not to ignore the additional bandwidth costs this is likely to incur. Have you considered working with the third-parties to add new IPs to their whitelists?

Comment: Too much work and too much bureaucracy involved (government and telecom sector). You make an excellent point @ceejayoz The nice thing is that I could exactly calculate the additional fees.

Comment: Might be worth it anyways. Start the process for several AWS, GCP, etc. IPs. Right now you've got a very big potential single point of failure.

Comment: Or you could move both web and DB and use the old IP address as a reverse proxy for these third parties.

Comment: @EsaJokinen the problem is that I want to connect to these third parties (outgoing) so I need my outgoing connections to go out from my old IP. Anyway I think this is doable with openvpn

Comment: 1ms is fine, Amazon AZs are about that far apart. The first thing I'd try is negotiating with the existing provider, maybe they give a customer retention discount. Adding an AWS web server will increases costs more than necessary IMHO, I'd probably keep the current web server and just add a DB server initially. VPN or encrypted database connection, either is fine, VPN costs a little money with AWS, and AWS bandwidth is expensive.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib yes, it's doable with OpenVPN.  I have a legacy app in another cloud service, with ALB in front, RDS as the database and the old dinosaur Solaris app server still in the other cloud.  Be sure to run OpenVPN in UDP mode -- you are likely to find an unexpectedly high amount of jitter over low-latency connections using TCP tunnels.